# How to read into R a directory of HTML files?

Tags: html, r, rvest

I have a file of HTML files I need to analyze.  How can I read in the entire directory of HTML files into R for processing?  Also, I need to apply a function from rvest to the HTML files iteratively to return a data frame that looks like:

```
HTML File | Updated Date
Url 1     | Date
Url 2     | Date
...
```

How can I accomplish this iterative process for a set of files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine **lapply** with **read_html** of **rvest** package as follow:

```
# Install rvest package em load it.
install.packages('rvest')
library(rvest)

# First create a variable with names of all html files.
html_names <- c('name1.html', 'name2.html', etc)

# reading all html files.
rawHTML <- lapply(html_names, function(html){
    read_html(html)
})
```

Output will be a list with all html files. Each element of it wil have one.

Hope was helpful.

Comment: I just saw this response! Sorry for the delay, but thank you so much for responding to me. The issue with this, is that I have more HTMLs than I can manage to list manually - somewhere in the realm of 200,000. But now I'm thinking, there may be a way to iteratively work through this list, with the RVEST package.

Comment: Hello, @MeredithAbrams, that's no problem! You can try this approach: first, put all your HTML files into just one folder and try this:

rawHTML <- lapply(dir("path_to_HTML_folder"), function(html){

   read_html(html)

})

dir function will create a vector with all HTML's and lapply function will iterate and read each of them, so you even don't need to know html's names.